# How can i call MVC View from Ajax.Post without returning to calling page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a web page that uses JavaScript to update a local array of objects, I would like to navigate to another page, passing the array of objects, this gets converted to a List, which I have working fine using Ajax.Post, but, I just want the return view(model) to display the page as it would if using an @Html.ActionScript, or @Url.Action. but it returns to the calling function, with a built up page.

is there a way of calling the post function as a 'fire and forget' type call ?

or is there a way of calling @Html.ActionScript or @UrlAction, passing the complex array as the parameter ?

here is some of the code that i am using

JS

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/About",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'clients': clients }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data){
        alert(data);
    },
    done: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(List<ClientDataModels> clients)
    {
        //Do something, all i need to do is pass the clients
        //to the view, and then dynamically add items based
        //on the content

        return View(clients);
    }
```

About.cshtml

```
    @using SST.Monitoring.Models
@model IEnumerable<ClientDataModels>
@{
    //Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<div class="container" style="width:900px">
    @if(@Model != null)
    { 
        foreach ( var client in @Model )
        {
            <div style="width:150px; float:left;">
                <div class="tile-container">
                    <div class="tile bg-cyan fg-white" data-role="tile">
                        <div class="tile-content iconic">
                            <span class="icon mif-display mif-2x"></span>
                            <span id="ClientCount" class="tile-badge bg-darkBlue">0</span>
                            <span class="tile-label">client.ClientGroup</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

the page that is returned to the ajax call has the 3 items( tiles ) which i expect, but i would like it to just fire and forget, and let the view just be displayed as it would be with @html.actionscript or event just a href link ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to achieve something like this.

You could have a method for rendering a view inside your controller.

```
public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, 
        string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData
                .GetRequiredString("action");

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines
                .FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, 
                viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

This method will create the html you need like if you're returning a view.

You must add this html to your response (json response).

```
return Json(new
{
    HtmlFromRenderPartialView = this.RenderPartialView("_SomeView", yourModel),
    Message = message
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And when you receive your ajax response, you will have the html and just `empty()` your container and `append(response.HtmlFromRenderPartialView)` to your container.

UPDATE:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public About(List<ClientDataModels> clients)
    {
        //Do something, all i need to do is pass the clients
        //to the view, and then dynamically add items based
        //on the content
      return Json(new
        {
    HtmlFromRenderPartialView = this.RenderPartialView("_About", clients),
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/About",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'clients': clients }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
       $('#container').html(response.HtmlFromRenderPartialView );
    },
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I do get a return value from the ajax.post call, and it is a success message, and I can view the message as html which shows what i expect, a html page, event if it doesn't have the styling applied. i am guessing what you have suggested above will return a partial view that i still need to do something with when the ajax call returns ? i was hoping that i can call @Url.Action and passing the viewmodel list as the argument ?

Comment: I didn't know a way to do what u want and i didn't think it exists. I have updated my answer accordingly to my initial idea and your update.

Comment: ah, ok, so i basically just create a partial view with the #container, and then update that way ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so based on the fact that I get the rendered page back as a result, I have just loaded it into the current window..

```
        var w = window.open("","_self");
        $(w.document.body).html(data.responseText);
```

This seems to have done the trick... thanks for your help !!